# Show $x^2$ in the interval $(0,1/3]$ has no fixed points.

Tags: analysis

Show $x^2$ in the interval $(0,1/3]$ has no fixed points.

I understand that the range of that domain is always lower than $y=x$, but what is a proper way of showing this? $$\left(0,\frac13\right] \to \left(0,\frac19\right]$$

Comment: Funny looking intervals!

Comment: @lhf: I now have a pain in the neck, straining to tilt my head to the right...

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x)=x^2$. You’re being asked to show that there is no $x\in(0,1/3]$ such that $f(x)=x$. Set up the equation $f(x)=x$, solve it, and discover that its only solutions are outside of $(0,1/3]$.

Comment: @lhf: Perfectly true, but that wasn’t the question.

Comment: Don't you mean that x > x^2 for (0,1) ?

Answer (score 2):

The quadratic equation $x^2=x$ can be written as $x^2-x=0$, and then as $x(x-1)=0$.  That has two solutions.  Neither of them is in the interval $(0,1/3]$.